# Restrict the columns represented in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How to change ActiveRecord so that it always has a restricted set of columns. I dont want all the columns in the backened table to present in the Model. This unnecessarily bloats the ActiveRecord's memory footprint as well as the time taken to query the record.

There are attributes like select ([ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M000333)) which can be used to SELECT only few columns. But is there any way we can force ActiveRecord to never query those columns inspite of the user performing just find without specifying `:select` all the time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use [default_scope](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-default_scope)

e.g.

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope select("column1, column2, column3")

  ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks. Didnt know that default_scope supported select also

Comment: `default_scope` will take any combination of relational methods and lambdas like a normal `scope` would

Answer (score 2):

Can't you do with a scope:

```
IGNORED = %w( id created_at updated_at )
scope :filtered, lambda { select( cols ) }

def self.cols
  attribute_names = []
  attributes = self.columns.reject { |c| IGNORED.include?( c.name ) }

  attributes.each { |attr| attribute_names << attr.name }
  attribute_names
end

Model.filtered
[#<Model name: "Test 2", reg_num: "KA 02", description: "aldsfjadflkj">]
```