# Rails legacy database connection, manually define columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So I can connect using the following code, but I have about 200 columns in the table. I'm only interested in 2 or 3 (e.g id, name, location).

How do I manually define these as the valid columns for the model?

```
class Legacy < ActiveRecord::Base

establish_connection({
   :adapter     => "postgresql",
   :host          => "localhost",
   :username => "myUser",
   :password => "myPass",
   :database => "legacy_db"
 })

self.table_name = 'account'

end
```

Comment: As I understand it, the column names should be automatically mapped for you.  You could have a look in `rails console` and call `Legacy.column_names` to see which are automatically detected.  If you see what you need there, you can set them with `attr_accessible` (below Rails 4) or via strong params in Rails 4

Comment: Yes but it's bombing on some id fields as it's trying to map relations.. So I just wanted to use a few fields.. I found out I can work around using pluck, but by default a Legacy.all will bomb rails

Comment: OK,in that case it may be worth looking at setting a default scope using for example http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/default_scope/class

Comment: Hey muttonlamb, you lead me to the answer thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Answered here: [Restrict the columns represented in ActiveRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8758455/restrict-the-columns-represented-in-activerecord)

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope select("column1, column2, column3")

  ...
end
```