# Ignore columns in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

I am trying to merge an old, legacy Rails 3 app into a more recent Django app.

Both apps used to use different databases, which are being merged into one unique database usable by both apps. The Django app will slowly take over the functionality of the old Rails app, starting with the migrations.

Django enforces strict database constraints in its migrations (e.g. `NOT NULL` fields with defaults). Any new fields on a table that is used by both apps will prevent Rails from updating records on that table, because ActiveRecord forcefully inserts `NULL` values instead of defaults.

Since we won't be adding new features to the Rails app, I'd like it to stick to a list of fields and ignore any newly-added fields.

The [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8758455/restrict-the-columns-represented-in-activerecord) using `default_scope` breaks other scopes, so I'd like to avoid it.

Triggers are an option, but I'm not keen on adding cruft to the Django app, just to deal with legacy code in the Rails app.

Hence : **Can I manually define columns in my models instead of letting ActiveRecord inspect the database automatically?**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Rails 5 solves your problem by providing `ignore_columns` option.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.ignored_columns = %w(employee_email)
end
```

`User.columns` will not give `employee_email` in the output.

Comment: Seems that there is no option for Rails 3 then. I'll accept the answer since it still provides useful information for those able to use Rails 5!

Answer (score 9):

You can accomplish what you want even in ancient versions of Rails (e.g. [Rails 2.3](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.17/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M001991)) by overriding `ActiveRecord::Base.columns`:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.columns
    super.reject { |c| c.name.in?(['column1', 'column2']) }
  end
end
```

This is [equivalent to `ignore_columns`](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/21720) in Rails 5.

Comment: If the model already has say column1 and I fetch using `as_json`, the column is present in response. If we want to avoid even the get so that its consistent, we can implement as_json on that model and add `options[:except] = [:column1, :column2]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ignorable gem if you are on a lower version of Rails

https://github.com/nthj/ignorable

ignore_columns :attributes